# how to fix the in crawl data issue

Tags: python, mongodb

i wrote some code to crawl data from google searching 
the code run but the data was not inserted to the database

i use python 3.7 and mongodb

```
while check<soBaiViet:
    i=0;
    try:
        thea=driver1.find_elements_by_xpath('''//div[@class='r']/a[1]|//g-inner-card/div/a[1]''')
        thetext=driver1.find_elements_by_xpath('''//div[@class='r']/a[1]/h3[@class='LC20lb']|//g-inner-card/div/a[1]''')
        while (i<len(thea)) and (sobaiviet<soBaiViet):
            google_search=db.newgoogle.find({'org_link':str(thea[i].get_attribute('href')).strip()})
            ds=[]
            for doc in google_search:
                ds.append(doc) 
            if(len(ds)==0):
                driver2.get(thea[i].get_attribute('href'))
                DSSource.append(str(driver2.page_source))
                document = {"id_user": "google-search", "id_post": "google-search", "title": str(thetext[i].text).strip(),"tutimkiem":tutimkiem,
                    "created_time": datetime.datetime.now(),"tags": "","source": str(driver2.page_source), "org_link": str(thea[i].get_attribute('href')).strip()}

                db.newgoogle.insertone(document)

            i=i+1 
            sobaiviet=sobaiviet+1
        check=check+i;
        driver1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pnnext"]').click() 
    except:
        break;
```

Comment: Google blocks you from crawling google has a security that blocks any robots or automatic program working on search engines. i think your code goes to `except` and `break` works and why did you write semicolons in your code :)))

Comment: can i fix that /???

Comment: try to shut down AWS `amazon web service` i really don`t know about how to shut down it but this works. ABout this you need to learn on your own :))

Comment: bro im really stuck with this. could you please help me .

Comment: There is another way that you can sleep your crawl with 120 sec or 60 sec interval and in one time crawl search once so that google will not block you i hope it works

Comment: do you have facebook so i can ask you more clearly ?